# php form redirection to other page and receiving the values

Tags: php

I have a php page with a form named "BuyForm" and a separate submit button.. like this

```
<form id="BuyForm" name="BuyForm" method="post" action="purchase.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
// form goes here
//example of one field
<div class="wrapper"> Your Name:
<input type="text" class="input" name="txtUserName" value="<?php if(isset($user_name)){echo $user_name;} ?>" <?php if(isset($flag) && $flag == 1){echo "error";}?> >
</div>
// more form options
```

This form is on this page "purchase.php". 
The reason of action="purchase.php" i.e. redirecting this form back to this page is that because all validation is in this page only.

Now there is a problem im stuck with and seek opinions..

1. I want to transfer these form values (for example name="txtUserName") to another page and I know i can directly do it via action="otherpage.php" and recieving there via php.
   But this could not be possible as i have to move all my current validations to that page (otherpage.php) and if anything is wrong then i have to redirect back to this form page (purchase.php) this will be waste of time and bandwidth and not a good coding..
   What else could be done in this case? i.e.  how can i send values from this page to that page?
2. in regards to Q-1 above how can i receive values on that page?

Thanks in anticipation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your $_POST values into array and send via header location.

My example:

```
$values = $_POST;

header('Location: other_page.php?'.http_build_query($values );
```

Comment: If you want to send values from form to another page through url then your form method must be "get". In your example you are sendindg hidden values through $_POST

Comment: Edited my answer, try my example.

Comment: can you show how can i make an array for two fields name="txtUserName" and take any other random like say name="txtUserEmail" and send those values?

Comment: $values['txtUserName'] = 'some user name';
$values['txtUserEmail'] = 'user email';

Comment: that means in order to add more fields to this array i shall keep $values common in all those and take the "name" of all those fields.. one by one.. is it so buddy?

Comment: Yes, you can do like that.

Comment: if i have already save this txtUserName to a php variable named $username and i want to use instead of txtUserName then how will this code be affected?? ($values['txtUserName'] = 'some user name';)

Comment: i want to do that cuz i have other fields which checked numbers using if else and based on that finally updated the related variable.. so in this case if i pick values from form that would be wrong values... or i again add if else to this posting array code

Comment: suppose i have a set of radio buttons having values 10, 20, 50 and other.. This other has a textfield associated to it.. means if user select other then he enters data into this other field.. if user slect "other radio" and i use above method and send radio button value.. there will be no value since user has selected text field inside that set of radio and the value is not of radio but of text field

Comment: means i do not want to send form values to another page... instead i want to send fully validated variables and all final values generated after all if else conditions

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25910/discussion-between-user2057047-and-croios)

Answer (score 0):

What about using session?

```
session_start();
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
   $_SESSION[$key]=$value;
}
```

With that you can access that value anywhere

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is "Q-1" you're talking about?

Comment: I want to transfer these form values (for example name="txtUserName") to another page and I know i can directly do it via action="otherpage.php" and recieving there via php. But this could not be possible as i have to move all my current validations to that page (otherpage.php) and if anything is wrong then i have to redirect back to this form page (purchase.php) this will be waste of time and bandwidth and not a good coding.. What else could be done in this case? i.e. how can i send values from this page to that page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

In your purchase.php:

```
if(!isset($_POST['var_name'])) {

//here the form code

}
else
{
//here's the validation
}
```